# Class Inheritance and Creation in Python

Tags: python, class, oop

When you create 2 classes in Python, does the second class always have to be a subclass or the child class? Is it possible to have two classes that have object as their parameters? Thanks!

```py
class Bird(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    print("A %s has feathers" % self.name)
 
class Seagull(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print("Seagulls can fly")
    super().__init__('Seagull')
 
seagull = Seagull()
```

What is wrong with this code? It says that Seagull is an inheritance so its (object) should be Bird... but why?

Comment: Question needs more details. Difficult to understand what is being asked

Comment: All classes inherit from `object` so they are all child classes in that sense. But you can have as many classes as you want. They don't have to inherit from each other. I'm not sure what you mean by "have object as their parameters". Since all objects trace back to `object` all paramters of any type are `object` at their root.

Comment: class Bird(object):
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    print("A %s has feathers" % self.name)
 
class Seagull(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print("Seagulls can fly")
    super().__init__('Seagull')
 
seagull = Seagull() 

What is wrong with this code? It says that Seagull is an inheritance so its (object) should be Bird... but why?

Comment: First of you don't need to inherit from `object`in python3, it is done automatically, so just write the classes as `class Bird:` and `class Seagull:`, second, the `super()` calls the parent object, which in this case is `object` and passes the given arguments (string in this case) but `object` takes no arguments. It is a bit confusing as to what you want to achieve

Comment: *"It says that Seagull is an inheritance"* -- What says that? If I run the code, I get `TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)` at `super().__init__('Seagull')`. Are you running this in some sort of code testing site? Please provide a [mre] including expected output and actual output. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The website, Codecademy says that it is wrong which is why you are getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you have subclasses or independent classes depends on the logic you're implementing.

With a bird and a seagull, you'd probably want a subclass, because a seagull is a kind of bird:

```
class Bird(object):
    ...

class Seagull(Bird):
    ...
```

In other situations, you would want separate classes, not related to each other:

```
class Bird(object):
    ...

class Locomotive(object):
    ...
```

---

By the way, in Python 3 the `(object)` part is not needed when it's literally `object`, so we would normally write:

```
class Bird:
    ...

class Seagull(Bird):
    ...

class Locomotive:
    ...
```

Comment: inheriting from `object` is redundant in python 3, just use `class Bird:`

Comment: Updated in the answer